# Having trouble copying information from one file to another in C

Tags: c, copy, switch-statement, transfer, fgetc

Was assigned a project to transfer information from one file to display a deposit or withdraw as D representing deposit and C representing C .The problem I'm having is the file "transactions.txt" is NULL and I can't figure out why.

Also is this part of my function correct?

```
float D(float balance, float deposit) {
    printf("and the amount is:");
    fputc(read, fpout, &deposit);
    printf("The balance is: %f", balance);
    return 0;
}
```

should i be using fputc or fscanf? I want it to display the output but also to save into the processed.txt file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fpin;
FILE *fpout;

float deposit;
float withdraw;
float balance;
float read;

//Function that asks the user for deposit information then prints balance + deposit.
float D(float balance, float deposit) {
    printf("and the amount is:");
    fputc(read, fpout, &deposit);
    printf("The balance is: %f", balance);
    return 0;
}

//Function that asks user for the amount they want withdrawn, then prints balance - withdrawal amount.
float C(float balance, float withdraw) {
    printf("and the amount is:");
    fputc(read, fpout, &withdraw);
    printf("The balance is %f", balance);
    return 0;
}    



int main(void) {

    char code;

    deposit = 0;
    withdraw = 0;
    balance = 0;

    //formula for balance.
    balance = balance + deposit;
    balance = balance - withdraw;

    //opens documents for inputs.
    fpin = fopen("transactions.txt", "r");
    fpout = fopen("processed.txt", "w");


    printf("Welcome to Chris's Checking Account Tracer Program");
    printf("\n------------------------------------------------------\n");

    //If file is null displays cannot open file. Else runs program.
    if ((fpin == NULL)) {
        printf("Cannot open file.");
    }
    else {

        //Runs a loop until the end of the file is reached.
        while (fpin!=EOF) {



        printf("The transaction is a: ");
        //Brings in information from "transaction.txt" input of code to output.
        read = getc(fpin);

    //Writes the output from transaction.txt to processed.txt
    fputc(read, fpout);

    // If user enters D or d runs 'D' Function.
    switch (code) {
    case 'D': case 'd':
        D(balance, deposit);
        break;

        // If user enters C or c runs 'C' Function.
    case 'C': case 'c':
        C(balance, withdraw);
        break;
        // If user enters anything else other then D or C prints "Not responding correctly".
    default:
        printf("Not responding Correctly.");
        break;
    }
    }
}
//closes the text documents.
fclose(fpin);
fclose(fpout);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Presumably the file "transactions.txt" which you open for reading does already exist, if so then it must be on a path other than the current path known to the executable.

Comment: Where does it open the file from?

Comment: IDK it mighht depend how you run the executable. Why not open the write file for output first, and find out where it was created (by using an unusual name)?

Comment: Re your later edit, `fputc` takes 2 arguments, you have given 3, why are you asking about an error the compiler will have caught? Apart from that it is highly optimistic to pass a `float` to a character output function.

Comment: "should i be using fputc or fscanf?" Ummm... `fputc()` is for output, `fscanf()` is for input... They're not even close to interchangeable...